# Share a hyperlink from Xamarin Forms application in Android apps(e.g. Whatsapp, Viber..)

Tags: hyperlink, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, whatsapp, android-sharing

I created a share option for Xamarin Forms app, using ***CrossShare*** class from ***Plugin.Share*** plugin, but when I share in Whatsapp, for example, I get the whole link like:

[image]

But what I really want is to have just text like on next picture without the whole link that will take me to the same location:

[image]

This is the code I used for sharing:

```
 CrossShare.Current.Share(new ShareMessage
        {
            Title = ApplicationConstants.ApplicationName,
            Text = "Nurnberg - Frankfurt 23.09.2017 00:00:00 7 €",
            Url = "http://www.checkmybus.com..."
        });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `Plugin.Share` didn't support Hyperlink,  if you want implement this feature, you should use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to implement in different platforms.

Comment: @York Shen  I'm not sure on what you mean? Which method should I use from the provided link? And how, should I write my own code for that?

Comment: Yes, if you want use this feature in `Xamrin.Forms`, you have to write your own code to implement it in different in different platforms, then you could use it in `Xamarin.Forms` by `DependencyService`.

Comment: @York Shen I asked the same question [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103723/share-a-hyperlink-from-xamarin-forms-application-in-android-apps-e-g-whatsapp-viber#latest) and they answered me that it's not possible to do something like that in WhatsApp API documentation for now

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenient, I read the whatsapp's document and Prashant Cholachagudda is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the current version of the Whatsapp application. I asked the same question [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103723/share-a-hyperlink-from-xamarin-forms-application-in-android-apps-e-g-whatsapp-viber#latest) and this is still not possible in the current API.

"Each application has their own implementation to handle the shared messages. The best option will be to shorten the link (using bit.ly or goo.gl) to make it user-friendly."

Hopefully, they will allow something like this soon.